# Java: Get Method on a Future from scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws InterruptedException {
  ScheduledExecutorService threadsPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  Future<?> f = threadsPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  Thread.sleep(5000);
  threadsPool.shutdown();
  System.out.println(threadsPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  try {
    f.get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Note the sleeping time of the evil thread: 1ms. This guarantees that the shutdown will be while the threads pool is waiting for the next iteration and the evil thread is not running.
This results in a a CancellationException on the get() method: If I understand correctly, ScheduledExecutorService cancels any pending task when calling shutdown(), so this behavior makes sense.

Next I have changed the sleeping time of evil thread from 1 to 1999. This guarantees that the shutdown will be during the sleeping of the evil thread.
This results in waiting forever on the get() method.

My next question is why is this behavior happening? Calling shutdown will gracefully shutdown the service. Indeed, the evil thread finishes the iteration and doesn't start again.
But why doesn't the get() method return? Am I misunderstanding the get() method on ScheduledFuture?
I thought that as soon as the evil thread finishes, and the pool is shutdown, the get() method should return null.

Answer (score 1):

If the future did not complete then it is possible that the `future.cancel()` method was invoked by the shutdown method (or the executor somehow cancelled the future).
This is the expected behavior of requesting the executor to shutdown, since it does not wait for tasks to complete.

If the future has been cancelled before finishing, throwing the `CancellationException` is the expected behavior. Otherwise it would wait for ether for the task to return.

In this case, since you use `ScheduledExecutorService` you can use the `ScheduledFuture` instead of `Future` in this case to get more information. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html 
This will allow you to access the `getDelay` method provided by the `Delayed` interface.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html

If you also check the source code of the method `scheduleAtFixedRate` you will see that it actually creates a `ScheduledFutureTask`. See code below. (Copy from source.)

```
/**
     * @throws RejectedExecutionException {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws NullPointerException       {@inheritDoc}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException   {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                                  long initialDelay,
                                                  long period,
                                                  TimeUnit unit) {
        if (command == null || unit == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        if (period <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        ScheduledFutureTask<Void> sft =
            new ScheduledFutureTask<Void>(command,
                                          null,
                                          triggerTime(initialDelay, unit),
                                          unit.toNanos(period));
        RunnableScheduledFuture<Void> t = decorateTask(command, sft);
        sft.outerTask = t;
        delayedExecute(t);
        return t;
    }
```

The `ScheduledFutureTask`'s `run` method automatically reexecutes it as soon as it is finished. (see last line of source code).

```
 /**
         * Overrides FutureTask version so as to reset/requeue if periodic.
         */
        public void run() {
            boolean periodic = isPeriodic();
            if (!canRunInCurrentRunState(periodic))
                cancel(false);
            else if (!periodic)
                ScheduledFutureTask.super.run();
            else if (ScheduledFutureTask.super.runAndReset()) {
                setNextRunTime();
                reExecutePeriodic(outerTask);
            }
        }
```

The `outerTask` is `this` so it is actually the ScheduledFutureTask itself. So it is never complete. For this reason you can never actually `get` the result.

Comment: Using `ScheduledFuture` as suggested shows that the delay is 0, that the future is done and is not cancelled. So how how can I cause the thread to 'done'. It seems that I don;r use the `get` correctly in this scenario.

Comment: I updated the answer to try and clarify your comment.  Perhaps get does not do what you would like to. If you want to get the result periodically and use it you should better include the code inside the task itself.

Comment: There is no missing code because, because my goal is to undestand the `get` method itself. What I am trying to do is to wait until the all the threads are finished and gracefully shut down the application, but still extract any exceptions that happened in the task (using the `get` method: Looks like the evil thread has finished and won't run again, and the thread pool is indeed shut down, so I can verify that all has finished and close my program? Using only `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` will prevent me from extracting any exceptions the the thread has thrown.

Comment: OK. Then the above should cover the question. The answer is briefly that using the 'get' method for a never-ending periodic task start with the 'scheduleAtFixedRate '  method will never return unless the task is cancelled.

Comment: Thank you. I still wonder how can I get the exception of the task if it threw one? In case there is no exception thrown from the task, the `get` will never return. But the only way to catch the exception is using get. Doing some more experiments showed that in case of exception, the `isDone` method of the future returns true, so looks like I should call `get()` only if `isDone()`. Is it correct?

Comment: It depends on what you would like to achieve and the Exception thrown. An exception inside the task could be handled inside the task body.
A programmer needs not handle every possible exception. Only checked exceptions should be handled.
Checking the `isDone()` or `isCancelled()` seems a nice approach. Because it also allows you to skip the blocking behaviour of `get()`.

Comment: I agree that not all exceptions should be handled. The body handles (hopefully) all the checked exceptions, but I want to at least log whatever wasn't catched for later investigation.